# TensorFlow unkown steps in first epoch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I tried to train my tensorflow model, but in the first epoch it just says x/unknown steps.. then it goes forever. 
After trying to set the epoch & validation steps the accuracy does not get better and often get stucked at 1, which is weird.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow is built to process iterators or generators as well as more static fixed-length inputs. In Python, `len(my_iterator)` is not defined. So, unless you specify `epochs` and `steps_per_epoch` (Note: not `validation_steps`), TensorFlow is not going to calculate the steps, in case the input is a iterator. Instead, it's going to iterate over the data until the data has been exhausted. If TensorFlow isn't explicitly told (via the parameters I mentioned)  how much data there is, it will display `x / unknown steps` for the first epoch. Having reached the end of the first epoch, however, TensorFlow will have discovered how much data there is, so following epochs will indicate the correct number of steps.

As for the accuracy reaching 1, that sounds perfectly expected to me. 1.0 or 100% is the maximum accuracy that is possible. In other words, your neural network is able to reproduce the output for your training data. For a more representative indication of performance, try setting aside some validation_data. That will likely be a bit lower and give you a better indication of how your network will perform on "wild" data.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Does the data stream get infinite by using the tensorflow data generator? Because it ran in the first epoch forever.

Comment: It shouldn't run forever. (Although I think I encountered a problem like that before.) If you set an expectation for more data than you have (by rounding up your epochs instead of rounding down, for example) that MIGHT happen. Hopefully tensorflow is smarter than that.

Comment: What are you using as a data source?

Comment: Keras Data Generators. For Example, this is some code: 
`datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, 
    validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    subset='training')`

Comment: Yeah, if you're using a generator, and it seems you are, then there's a chance tensorflow is expecting more data. I'm not familiar with these functions but, with my generator input, I need to multiply my source data by `epoch` times. Each epoch consumes all the data. n epochs requires n * data. I don't know if that's your problem, but that sounds like the right path.